# Center align the items in the keystroke package

Tags: alignment

I am using the keystroke package to create keyboard icons. However several of the items are not center aligned. For example, the single digit numbers are all right aligned which makes the button look odd. How do I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{keystroke}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \keystroke{0},\keystroke{1} ...\keystroke{9}: The digits 0 through to 9.
        \item \keystroke{+}: Addition
        \item \keystroke{$-$}: Subtraction
        \item \keystroke{$*$}: Multiplication
        \item \keystroke{$/$}: Division
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\suse@keystr@ke
  {\hbox to 0pt{\unhbox\suse@key\hss}}
  % \suse@key = \hbox{{\keystroke@font\strut#1}}
  % \@tempdimb = max(\wd\suse@key, \dp\suse@key)
  {\hbox to 0pt{\hbox to \@tempdimb{\hss\unhbox\suse@key\hss}\hss}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \keystroke{0},\keystroke{1} ...\keystroke{9}: The digits 0 through to 9.
        \item \keystroke{+}: Addition
        \item \keystroke{$-$}: Subtraction
        \item \keystroke{$*$}: Multiplication
        \item \keystroke{$/$}: Division
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is much better!

Answer (score 1):

This code is tricky, but works!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{keystroke}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \keystroke{\,0},\keystroke{\,1} ...\keystroke{\,9}: The digits 0 through to 9.
        \item \keystroke{+}: Addition
        \item \keystroke{$-$}: Subtraction
        \item \keystroke{$\,*$}: Multiplication
        \item \keystroke{$\,/$}: Division
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you have to make some edit(s) in the package implementation.